# Javascript Error in IE9 "SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)"

Tags: javascript

**When I debug in IE9, It breaks on the following line**

```
{var c=document.createElement('<iframe id="'+a+'" name="'+a+'" />')
```

**with the following error:**

```
SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5) 
wmd.js, line 1 character 97
```

I am using OSQA software, and the bug may be reproduced with the latest version of IE9 (possibly with web developer toolbar installed)

http://meta.osqa.net/questions/ask/  (bug may be reproduced as of 1/3/12)

If you visit that page, open up the javascript console, and attempt to upload any image using the image uploader, the error occurs.

This only breaks on IE9 for some reason

## Update

I'm a bit new to this javascript debugging business, but I opened up the watch menu and the value of "a" is: `jUploadFrame1325624808664`

Comment: The `wmd.js` where this error occurs seem to be a 3rd party library. Report it to the library's maintainer.

Comment: Since that is part of some minified javascript, I recommend splitting it out for debugging. You want to be absolutely certain where the error is occurring. See http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `createElement` method [expects *only* the name of the element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create. Like this:

```
var c = document.createElement("iframe")
```

Properties can be added to the new element later:

```
c.id = c.name = a;
```

*Previous versions* of IE allowed you to provide this function with arbitrary HTML, but that was never part of [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/) and is no longer supported in IE9.

Answer (score 3):

To use `createElement`, you should only give it a tag name.

```
var c = document.createElement('iframe');
c.id = c.name = a;
```

Comment: Setting the name elements on IE6 creates an exception, and the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534184(VS.85).aspx indicates that there are problems with IE7 as well.  That's why the funky IE6 method is being used in the first place.  Either try / catch or determine if you can "detect" the "feature" (or lack thereof in IE6).

Answer (score 1):

```
var c=document.createElement('iframe');
c.id=a;
```