# Syntax error, unrecognized expression / ASP.NET / ColorBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, syntax-error, colorbox

I have an ASP.NET page with a link like this:

`http://page/SitePages/Show.aspx?stringone=3&stringtwo=1&lang=en`

I'm using ColorBox and jQuery v1.10.1.

I'm getting an error like this when I'm trying to open the link in ColorBox (iframe):

```
SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression
```

What's causing this and how it can be resolved? Thanks.

Comment: We'll need the actual code where the link is.  Also, maybe this will help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718602/javascript-error-in-ie9-script5022-dom-exception-invalid-character-err-5

Comment: The link looks like this: `<a href="Show.aspx?stringone=3&stringtwo=1&lang=en" class="colorBox">Show the page</a>`

Comment: Which browser are you using when you get this error... does it appear in all browsers you test on, or just on IE7 (which I'm guessing you're testing in)?

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by selectors. You are probably using an unvalid selector. The format of it could be wrong or it doesnt match any objects.

To catch which one actually causes the error, you can get a hint from console debuggers of browsers. In chrome hit F12 and go to console tab. In firefox, you should download a plugin "firebug" and hit F12.